# Decode funny ISO encoding of e-mail message

Tags: c++, email, unicode, codepages

I have an e-mail body (char[] buffer, retrieved via POP3), it apparently uses some markup for ISO code pages, e.g. a subject like

```
Daß ißt ään schlümmer Test
```

is encoded as

```
=?iso-8859-1?Q?Da=DF_i=DFt_=E4=E4n_schl=FCmmer_TDest
```

Is there anything pre-made I can use to turn that into a (readable) CStringW?

(Environment: Win32, C++, VC2008.)

Comment: This MIME encoding is called [quoted-printable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This format is called an `encoded-word` and is defined by [RFC 2047](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2047.txt). The form is `=?<charset>?<Q or B>?<encoded data>?=`, where the data is encoded as either base-64 (B) or something that looks like quoted-printable (Q) but isn't quite (because `_` means a space).

[Some](http://csourcesearch.com/cpp/fid7C62A549167E5E3692EEDBE4F75B46FC42FB2902.aspx?s=cdef%3Amd5) [example](http://dev.mutt.org/hg/mutt/file/b01d63af6fea/rfc2047.c) C++ decoders will get you to a byte string. You'd then have to decode using the charset to get a Unicode string.